# need some help on java method showMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing, debugging

here is my code:

```
//DebugTwo4.java

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DebugTwo4
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String costString;
      double cost;
      double tax = 0.06;

      costString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
         "Enter price of item you are buying", "Purchases",
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      cost = Double.parseDouble("cost");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"With " + tax * 100 + "% tax, purchase is $" + cost + cost     * tax);
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

and the error message is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cost"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at DebugTwo4.main(DebugTwo4.java:16)

Comment: `cost = Double.parseDouble("cost");`  "Double" check that line.

Comment: @user2731240 "cost" is string value not a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"cost"` is not a double...

Therefore, this will fail...

```
cost = Double.parseDouble("cost");
```

I think you meant

```
cost = Double.parseDouble(costString);
```

You may also want to consider using a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) or even [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which are designed to restrict what the user enters...

Comment: thanks~ my first time to post on stack overflow, I've figured out the mistake myself though

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
Double.parseDouble("cost");
```

parseDouble method expects a string that represents a valid `double` value but you are passing "cost" to it, which is invalid.

Instead i believe you need to pass the `costString` variable to it as that is reading a double value in it:

```
Double.parseDouble(costString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
  {
     cost = Double.valueOf(costString);
  }
 catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
      System.out.println("NumberFormatException occured");
  }
```

instead of

```
Double.parseDouble("cost");
```